# Geoserver WPS - CORS Problem

Tags: geoserver, wps, cors

I'm working with Geoserver 2.12.1 (Windows Installer Version) and I had to enable CORS before for getting access when I attempted to do a `GetFeatureInfo`.

I did the steps to enable CORS:

1. Edit `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

> ```
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
>   <init-param>
>       <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
>       <param-value>*</param-value>
>   </init-param>
>   <init-param>
>       <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
>       <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
>   </init-param>
>   <init-param>
>       <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
>       <param-value>origin, content-type, accept</param-value>
>   </init-param>
> </filter>
>
> <!-- 
>   THIS FILTER MUST BE THE FIRST ONE, otherwise we end up with ruined chars in the input from the GUI
>   See the "Note" in the Tomcat character encoding guide:
>   http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding
> -->
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

Now, the `GetFeatureInfo` for `WMS Service` is working, but, I recently installed **WPS Plugin** and when I do some request to:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wps

It's not working. It's showing the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
(index):1 Failed to load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wps: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

But I have it configured to accept all methods.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an authorised user to to make WPS requests, so add a user name and password to the request. Admin/geoserver will work if you haven't set up any specific users and changed the default password.

Answer (score 0):

Should enable access allowing domain in CSRF. Edit Geoserver´s web.xml and add comma separated allowed domains or IPs your server can be reached (Not client IPs).

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST</param-name>
    <param-value>yourdomain.com,192.168.x.y</param-value>
</context-param>
```